# Como implementar o tema Gentelella Bootstrap Admin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, bootstrap

Galera estou começando agora com desenvolvimento web no Visual Studio. Já entendi o MVC, tenho algum conhecimento de HTML e comecei a estudar o bootstrap. Descobri na web este belíssimo modelo **Free Bootstrap 3 Admin Template**
Que tem um exemplo online aqui:
https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html

Eu baixei os arquivos e tals como estão nesta imagem...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não faço idéia de como coloca-lo no meu projeto. Ou seja eu já tenho criado um novo projeto Dot.Net MVC limpo no Visual Studio Community 2015. Fiz uns testes... criei uns controllers e tals... **Agora como altero o bootstrap padrão que veio no projeto para este que baixei?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então... Encontrei tudo que precisava aqui:

[Video do youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOLXdGbZ96c)
intitulado "Plantilla Bootstrap en Proyecto ASP.NET MVC" (obviamente em espanhol)

São muitas etapas: Adição dos arquivos ao projeto, configuração do _Layout, das referencias, do bundles, etc. E no fim deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Então, lembrando dos seus conhecimentos de HTML: você lembra que lá dentro do elemento `<head>` você faz referência aos arquivos `CSS` que você vai usar no seu site para alterar a aparência dos elementos `html`, certo? É o elemento `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/estilos.css" />` ou coisa que o valha.

Daí, você precisa carregar os estilos desse tema aí depois de carregar os estilos do bootstrap. Se você olhar o código do demo do site, está assim a ordem de carregamento das folhas de estilo:

```
<link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NProgress -->
<link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
<link href="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQVMap -->
<link href="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
<link href="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
<link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ou seja: ele traz o bootstrap na primeira linha desse trecho, depois traz as outras coisas que ele usa (Font Awesome, NProgress e tal) e no final traz o estilo personalizado do tema. Isso pois o `CSS` carregado por último sempre sobreescreve o carregador anteriormente, por isso são "Folhas de Estilo em Cascata" (Cascading Style Sheets).

Estude bem HTML, a pior coisa que tem é um programador web que não saca de HTML e HTTP.

Enfim, bons estudos pra você.

Comment: Obrigado @Daniel ! Então eu copio todos aqueles arquivos e pastas que baixei pra dentro da pasta do meu projeto. E altero o _Layout.cshtml da pasta Views\Shared para carregar esses estilos... Só isso? Preciso alterar alguma configuração no Web.config... ou algo assim?

Comment: Provavelmente não precisa fazer nada, só carregar os arquivos que estiverem na pasta do projeto. Mas também não sei tanto sobre o ``IIS``, testa e vê se funciona.

Comment: Basicamente é o que o @Daniel disse, eu já utilizei este tema em um painel e bastou satisfazer as chamadas no arquivo '_Layout'.

Assim como no uso do bootstrap você deve respeitar a ordem das inserções de arquivos de estilo (css) e de scripts (javascript) pra que tudo funcione.

Algumas páginas podem exigir scripts extras para funcionarem.
Uma dica é que caso algo dê errado verifique no console de depuração d navegador o erro para ver se não ficou nada sem estar referenciado ou fora da ordem esperada